# How to connect a C64 with a PC display?

Tags: monitor, commodore-64

A friend of mine has an old C64, it has a video output 
[image]
and we are wondering how to connect this with an VGA or DVI computer monitor?

Comment: @powtac You can try a getting a S Video/Video To VGA Converter.

Comment: Not sure about the video plug, but I remember just using a male-male composite cable to plug it into a TV, but maybe that's not an option?

Comment: There was a male to male composite cable with the box... But we want to run it with a PC display.

Answer (score 4):

The route I initially took with this question was to use a couple converters, something like RF to RCA to VGA. This gentleman was able to accomplish this with a little work:

http://www.commodoreserver.com/BlogEntryView.asp?EID=F4B967500A894E10BE4A104C65DB541E

Another route may be a converter box, which tend to cost a little more money but don't require the labor to get working. Something like this from eBay may be appropriate:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=120619073385

If you go with the converter box route, make sure it has either an RF or 8-pin S-Video input (I say 8-pin just to be sure even though RandInLA from the first article says pins 7 and 8 aren't even internally connected).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to make a S-Video cable :
http://radagast.ca/C64_svideo/C64_Svideo.html
This is the C-64 pinout [image: C-64 pinout] (the early version of the C64 only has pins 1 to 5)

The S-Video looks like this [image: S-Video]

So the objective is to create a patch cable that goes something like this:

```
C64 Pin S-Video Pin 
2       1   
2       2   
4 or 6  3   
1       4
```

If you have an early C64, you must use pin 4 as your chrominance signal. If you have a later 8 pin A/V connector, then you can use pin 6.

I already have a C64 to 1702 monitor cable. This cable breaks the C64 A/V port into three RCA jacks: audio, chroma, and luma (sync on luma). So I will cheat. I will make a crossover cable. The aim of the crossover cable is to take the RCA luma and chroma inputs from my C64 cable and cross the conductors to the S Video mini DIN output. I will do this by cutting up a pair of old RCA cables and a S-Video cable. The resulting crossover cable looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please don't just leave a link, summarize the page that you link to in case it ever goes down.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Commodore_C128/C64C_Video) the video jack only provides composite output like the RF jack, so what you are looking for is a composite to VGA or DVI converter.